# Kendo Unable to get property 'data' of undefined or null reference

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI grid with Angular. I am trying to send grid updates to my MVC controller, but when I click the Update button in the grid I am receiving the error "Unable to get property 'data' of undefined or null reference"

Here is my Angular controller code for my grid:

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "/SSQV4/SSQV5/Search/GetBusinessUnits"
                },

                update: {
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "/SSQV4/SSQV5/Operator/UpdateBusinessUnit"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ProductID",
                    fields: {
                        intOrder: { editable: false },
                        OperatorBusinessUnitID: { editable: false },
                        vchDescription: { editable: true },
                        vchOperatorSystemID: {editable: true}
                    }
                }
          },
            sort: { field: "intOrder", dir: "asc" }
        }),

        batch: false,
        reorderable: true,
        sortable: false,
        editable: "inline",
        columns: [
          { template: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up" style="cursor:pointer" ng-click="MoveUp(#=OperatorBusinessUnitID#)"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" ng-click="MoveDown(#=OperatorBusinessUnitID#)" style="cursor:pointer"></i>', title: "List Order", width:100 },
          { field: "intOrder", hidden: true},
          { field: "OperatorBusinessUnitID", title: "Business Unit ID" },
          { field: "vchDescription", title: "Business Unit Name" },
          { field: "vchOperatorSystemID", title: "Operator System ID"},
          {
              command: [
                { name: "edit", text: " " },
                { name: "destroy", text: " " },
              ], title: "Action"
          }
        ]
    };
```

Here is my MVC controller method:

```
public ActionResult UpdateBusinessUnit(OperatorBusinessUnitModel form)
{
    CompanyClient.UpdateBusinessUnit(form);
    var businessunits = CommonClient.GetBusinessUnitsByMajorID(UserInfo.intMajorID);
    return Json(businessunits, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: what is the version of kendo you are using , get the output from console using `kendo.version`

Comment: tried looking in console for kendo.version, but don't see it.  Is there any other way to get the version?

Comment: are you sure kendo is loaded in your page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues causing my problem here.  First, the scheme had Product ID as the id, and it should have been OperatorBusinessUnitID.  (That's what I get for copying examples.)  The issue is that the UpdateBusinessUnit method in my MVC controller needed to be changed to a void rather than an ActionResult returning the entire recordset.  It seems to be working correctly now.